# AttributeError no attribute 'delete'

Tags: python, django

i am working on a website where users can send friend request, accept request, cancel request. I have an error AttributeError object has no attribute 'delete'. This happens when i cancel friend request. This my code i tried:

Model:

```
class FriendRequest(models.Model):
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='to_user')
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='from_user')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null= True) 

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Friend request'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Friend requests'
    ordering = ['-date']

def __str__(self):
    return "from {}, to {}".format(self.from_user.username, self.to_user.username)
```

Views.py:

```
@login_required
def cancel_friend_request_view(request, id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    frequest = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user, to_user=user).first()
    frequest.delete()
    print(frequest)
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`.first()` will return `None` if no matching row is found.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#first

> Note that first() is a convenience method, the following code sample is equivalent to the above example:
>
> ```
> try:
>     p = Article.objects.order_by('title', 'pub_date')[0]
> except IndexError:
>     p = None
> ```

---

[edit] you need to handle the `None`-case, which should have been clear from the above explanation. Also, I recommend to learn using the python debugger to inspect types of variables instead of relying on debug-prints.

```
@login_required
def cancel_friend_request_view(request, id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    frequest = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user, to_user=user)
    if frequest is None:
       raise Http404()
    frequest.delete()
```

Comment: @ACimander...i tried your code but the friend request is not cancelling/deleting. def cancel_friend_request_view(request, id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    try:
        frequest = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user, to_user=user)[0]
    except IndexError:
        frequest = None
        frequest.delete()
        print(frequest)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

Comment: @MrHize the above code just demonstrates how .first() works. In your case: frequest can be None, and None is not a django model object and doesn't have the method .delete(). That's why you get an AttributeError.

Comment: @ACimander..This is another challenging question, please check if you can help out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62192936/why-is-button-not-toggling

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this(I do not know if it is the best way, but it worked), removing .first():

```
@login_required
def cancel_friend_request_view(request, id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    frequest = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user, to_user=user)
    frequest.delete()
    print(frequest)
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to pass through the FriendRequest's ID instead, to entirely skip this section of code:

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
frequest = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user, to_user=user).first()
```

You could rather do this:

```
friend_request = get_object_or_404(FriendRequest, id=id)
friend_request.delete()
```

Also consider not deleting data entirely from your database, and rather making use of deleted flags in order to keep a behavioural history throughout your software.

Comment: @Elandre...you code is not deleting FriendRequest in database. When I click on cancel button it does nothing. I have updated the code that work for me

Comment: This is another challenging question, please check if you can help out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62192936/why-is-button-not-toggling