# Why is button not toggling

Tags: python, django

i am working on a website where users can send friend request, accept request and cancel request. I have a problem on button toggling, when a user send me a friend request the botton on my side displays 'follow back', when i click on the 'follow back' button the button supposed to change to 'following', but it does not. I will attached an image to make my question a bit more specific.
Note: Both images are from different template and views, the first image is where the problem is at. As you can see in my first image, the button still remain on FOLLOW BACK when it is clicked, when clicked the button should change to FOLLOWING but it not. What am i missing in my code?

[image]

[image]

Model:

```
class FriendRequest(models.Model):
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='to_user')
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='from_user')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null= True) 

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Friend request'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Friend requests'
    ordering = ['-date']

def __str__(self):
    return "from {}, to {}".format(self.from_user.username, self.to_user.username)
```

Views.py:

```
@login_required
def following_view(request, username):
    p = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user__username=username).exclude(
    Q(from_user__profile__friends__blocked_by__user__username=username)|
    Q(from_user__profile__blocked_users__user=request.user)|
    Q(to_user__profile__blocked_users__user=request.user))

    all_profile_users = []
    button_status_list = []

    for user_obj in p:
        u = user_obj.to_user
        all_profile_users.append(u)
        friends = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user, friends__id=user_obj.id).exists()
        button_status = 'none'
        if not friends:
            button_status = 'not_friend'

            if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(
                from_user=request.user).filter(to_user=u)) == 1:
                button_status = 'cancel_request_sent'

            if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(
                from_user=u).filter(to_user=request.user)) == 1:
                button_status = 'follow_back_request'

        button_status_list.append(button_status)

    context = {
        'owner_of_the_following': request.user.username == username,
        'profile_and_button_status': zip(p,button_status_list),
        'u': all_profile_users,
        'following': p,
    }

    return render(request, 'following.html', context)
```

Template:

```
<div class="card news-card mb-2" id="suggested-people-card" style="width:700px;padding:13px;box-shadow:none;"> 
{% for data in profile_and_button_status %}
<!-- Copy and paste for another post below -->
  <div class="row mb-3">

   {% if data.0.to_user.profile.profile_pic %}
   <a href="{% url 'site:profile-view' data.0.to_user.username %}">
    <img src="{{ data.0.to_user.profile.profile_pic.url }}" class="rounded-circle avatar-img ml-4" height="50" width="50" style="border:none;padding:0px;position:relative;top:-1px;object-fit: cover;">
    </a>
    {% endif %}

   <div class="suggestionfrndnamemutual-cont mt-1 ml-3"> 
    <p class="dark-grey-text text-lowercase font-weight-bold">
      <a href="{% url 'site:profile-view' data.0.to_user.username %}"><span class="suggestionfrnd-username username dark-grey-text text-truncate" style="">
      {{ data.0.to_user.username }}</span></a>
    </p>     
    <p class="card-text" style="position:relative;top:0px;">
      <span class="suggestionfrnd-mutual text-muted" style="font-size:13px;">New to Pixmate</span>
    </p>
  </div>

  {% if not data.0.to_user == request.user %}
   <div class="mt-2" style="position:absolute;right:30px;">
    {% if data.1 == 'not_friend' %}
     <a href="{% url 'site:send_friend_request' data.0.to_user.id %}" class="friend-request">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block waves-effect text-capitalize font-weight-bold p-1" style="box-shadow:none;font-size:13px;width:100px;border-radius:30px;">
        <span style="padding-right:10px;" class="ml-2">Follow</span>
      </button>
    </a>
    {% elif data.1 == 'cancel_request_sent' %}
    <a href="{% url 'site:cancel_friend_request' data.0.to_user.id %}" class="friend-request">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-amber btn-sm btn-block waves-effect text-capitalize font-weight-bold p-1" style="box-shadow:none;font-size:13px;width:100px;border-radius:30px;">
        <span style="padding-right:10px;" class="ml-2">Cancel</span>
      </button>
    </a>
    {% elif data.1 == 'follow_back_request' %}
    <a href="{% url 'site:accept_friend_request' data.0.to_user.id %}" class="friend-request">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block waves-effect text-capitalize font-weight-bold p-1" style="box-shadow:none;font-size:13px;width:100px;border-radius:30px;">
        <span style="padding-right:10px;" class="ml-2">Follow Back</span>
      </button>
    </a>

    {% else %} <!-- THIS BUTTON IS NOT SHOWING -->
    <a href="{% url 'site:remove_friend' data.0.to_user.id %}" class="friend-request">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block border waves-effect text-capitalize font-weight-bold dark-grey-text p-1" style="box-shadow:none;font-size:13px;width:100px;border-radius:30px;">
        <span style="padding-right:10px;" class="ml-2">Following</span>
      </button>
    </a>

    {% endif %}
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  </div> 
<!-- Row Grid -->
{% endfor %} 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no mentioning of what should happen on clicking "follow back"
Use javascript onclick() function to define that on clicking of "follow back" button it should change to "following back".

Comment: @Shivam...I will try using jquery, although I was able to do this in user profile page without using jquery. But I will try to use jquery on this path.

Comment: @Shivam...I tried using jquery but having complications. Please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62210323/how-to-hide-and-show-button-after-page-reload