# How to hide and show button after page reload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am learning jQuery and I have issues on how to hide and show a button during page reload. I tried my code below, it hides and shows the button on click, but when the page loads, the button changes back to former state. This is what I've tried:

Template:

```
<span class="load-requests-sections"> <!-- Load page if request sent in Ajax -->
<!-- Main -->
<main>

<!-- Container -->
<div class="container-fluid" id="suggested-people-cont" style="position:relative;top:170px;padding-bottom:100px;">

<!-- Row Grid Container -->
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-9 col-12"> 
{% if following %}
<h6 class="suggested-people-header mb-3" style="font-weight:500;">Following {{ following.count|human_format }}</h6>
{% endif %}

<div class="card news-card mb-2" id="suggested-people-card" style="width:700px;padding:13px;box-shadow:none;"> 
{% for data in profile_and_button_status %}
<!-- Copy and paste for another post below -->
  <div class="row mb-3">

   {% if data.0.to_user.profile.profile_pic %}
   <a href="{% url 'site:profile-view' data.0.to_user.username %}">
    <img src="{{ data.0.to_user.profile.profile_pic.url }}" class="rounded-circle avatar-img ml-4" height="50" width="50" style="border:none;padding:0px;position:relative;top:-1px;object-fit: cover;">
    </a>
    {% endif %}

   <div class="suggestionfrndnamemutual-cont mt-1 ml-3"> 
    <p class="dark-grey-text text-lowercase font-weight-bold">
      <a href="{% url 'site:profile-view' data.0.to_user.username %}"><span class="suggestionfrnd-username username dark-grey-text text-truncate" style="">
      {{ data.0.to_user.username }}</span></a>
    </p>     
    <p class="card-text" style="position:relative;top:0px;">
      <span class="suggestionfrnd-mutual text-muted" style="font-size:13px;">New to Pixmate</span>
    </p>
  </div>

  {% if not data.0.to_user == request.user %}
   <div class="mt-2" style="position:absolute;right:30px;">
    {% if data.1 == 'not_friend' %}
     <a href="{% url 'site:send_friend_request' data.0.to_user.id %}" class="friend-request">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block waves-effect text-capitalize font-weight-bold p-1" style="box-shadow:none;font-size:13px;width:100px;border-radius:30px;">
        <span style="padding-right:10px;" class="ml-2">Follow</span>
      </button>
    </a>
    {% elif data.1 == 'cancel_request_sent' %}
    <a href="{% url 'site:cancel_friend_request' data.0.to_user.id %}" class="friend-request">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-amber btn-sm btn-block waves-effect text-capitalize font-weight-bold p-1" style="box-shadow:none;font-size:13px;width:100px;border-radius:30px;">
        <span style="padding-right:10px;" class="ml-2">Cancel</span>
      </button>
    </a>
    {% elif data.1 == 'follow_back_request' %}
    <!-- CLICK ON THIS BUTTON TO HIDE AND SHOW THE BELOW BUTTON -->
    <a href="{% url 'site:accept_friend_request' data.0.to_user.id %}" class="friend-request followback-btn">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block waves-effect text-capitalize font-weight-bold p-1" style="box-shadow:none;font-size:13px;width:100px;border-radius:30px;">
        <span style="padding-right:10px;" class="ml-2">Follow Back</span>
      </button>
    </a>

    <!-- SHOW THIS BUTTON AFTER PAGE RELOAD -->
    <a href="{% url 'site:remove_friend' data.0.to_user.id %}" class="friend-request following-btn" style="display:none;">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block border waves-effect text-capitalize font-weight-bold dark-grey-text p-1" style="box-shadow:none;font-size:13px;width:100px;border-radius:30px;">
        <span style="padding-right:10px;" class="ml-2">Following</span>
      </button>
    </a>

    {% endif %}
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  </div> 
<!-- Row Grid -->
{% empty %}
  {% if owner_of_the_following %}
  <div class="container text-center image-post mt-0">
  <!-- <img src="{{ '/static/' }}images/photo-camera-img.png" class="mb-3" width="60" height="60"> -->
  <p class="dark-grey-text" style="font-size: 28px;">People you're Following</p>
  <p class="dark-grey-text">When you follow someone, it will show here.</p>
  <a href="{% url 'site:people-suggested' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md waves-effect mx-auto my-4" style="box-shadow:none;border-radius:30px;">
  <strong>Find People to Follow</strong></a>
  </div>
  {% else %}
  <div class="container text-center image-post mt-0">
  <p class="dark-grey-text"><strong>No users</strong></p>
  </div>
  {% endif %}


{% endfor %} 

</div>    
<!-- Card -->
</div>
<!-- Column Grid -->

</div>
<!-- Row Grid Container -->
</div>
<!-- Container -->

</main>
<!-- Main -->
</span>
```

Jquery:

```
//SEND FRIEND REQUESTS WITHOUT PAGE RELOAD THIS WORKED
$('.load-requests-sections').on('click', '.friend-request', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var page = $(this).attr('href');
  $('.load-requests-sections').load(page);
});

//HIDE AND SHOW BUTTON AFTER PAGE RELOAD RETURN BACK TO OLD STATE WHEN PAGE RELOAD
$('.followback-btn').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.followback-btn').hide();
  $('.following-btn').show();
})
```

I also tried using localstorage, to show the hidden button after the page reloads, but the old button clicked is still shown. How do I hide the old button after a page reload.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var $hidden = $('.following-btn');

   if (localStorage.getItem('show')) {
      $hidden.show();
      $('.followback-btn').hide();
   }

   $('.followback-btn').on('click', function() {
      localStorage.setItem('show', true);
      window.location.reload(false); 
   });
})
```

Comment: so you just want the previous state of button on page load? if you hide it, it should be hidden if its visible then it should be visible on page refrsh, right?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem in how you test if the `.followback-btn` was pressed.

In your second jQuery example, try replacing this line:

```
localStorage.getItem('show') && $hidden.show();
```

With this:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('show')) {
    $hidden.show();
    $('.followback-btn').hide();
}
```

This means that if the `show` variable is set in the local storage, the `.following-btn` will be shown when the page loads, instead of the `.followback-btn` one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Romi...i replaced my code to yours. When I clicked on follow back button, page reload and follow back button still show. How do I make following button show when page reload?

Comment: @MrHize just to make sure, you are running your jQuery code AFTER the page has finished loading, right?

Comment: By that I mean your code is running in `$(document).ready( function() {...});`

Comment: @Romi...I added document.ready. i think your code is close to what I want. I'm using your code but the problem now is, the follow back button do not show anymore. I want it to be like, show the follow back button, then when click on the follow back button then hide the follow back button and show following button

Comment: @MrHize If I understand correctly your last comment, you now have the `show` variable in your local storage, and now the 'followback' button won't show on other users. To solve this, you need to save the user id your are following, not just `show`.

Comment: @Romi...yes follow back button do not show anymore only following. Help me, when I click on follow back then page reload and display following button

Comment: @MrHize I have explained what you need to do to fix that problem. You need to add the user id your are following to your `show` storage variable. It should be something like `show-[USER ID]`, otherwise there will be no way to differentiate between the users your are following and which not.

Comment: @Romi...okay I will try to see if I can fix this

Comment: @Romi...this is not working, I am passing the ID in template {{data.id}}

Comment: @MrHize could you update your question with the new code? Specifically how you add the user id to the two buttons, and how the jQuery query reflects the change.

Comment: I have update my question in jQuery, replacing your code. check.

Comment: In my opinion, it would be easier to handle your use case on the server. Currently, using local storage won't guarantee consistency across devices. For example, if I follow a user on my PC, then log in on my mobile, I could send another request. Also, with this approach, you would have to save a storage item for each user I want to follow.

Comment: @Romi...your code is closer to what I want, but the problem is. When user A send request to user B, when user B login it automatically shows user A and user B are following each other, without user B clicking follow back. It should be when user A send a request to user B, when user B login it shows follow back button to user A, and when user B click follow back, the button will then show following. Which indicates that user B have accepted the request of user A.

Comment: That is because the item in localstorage, `show`, applies to both user A and user B. If one sends a follow request, if you log in with the other, the same storage is used. That's what I've been saying all along. You need to handle the follow requests on the server side.